# Ruby on Rails: How do I get the Model name from inside the Controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say the controller name is `TemplateUserController` whose model class is `TemplateUser`.

Now, I could do `self.name.tableize.singularize.string_manipulation…`
but that seems a little excessive… I was wondering if there was a faster way to get the model name from the controller. Thanks! =D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A more direct way to do this: `controller_name.classify`.

Comment: Then, to get the class I just added .constantize at the end =D

Answer (score 3):

You probably know that you can't guarantee a 1-to-1 mapping between controllers and models.

However, in the cases where you can, `CanCan` is a gem which needs to do the same thing you're after, and it does it like this:

```
def model_name
  params[:controller].sub("Controller", "").underscore.split('/').last.singularize
end
```

Because there isn't an implied link between model and controller (except by convention), making your own judgements based on the controller name is the only way to go.

Comment: But, assuming for all the instances where I need to get the model name from the controller name, the model name is in the controller name... how would I do that?  I'd use your method with the .sub, but I do some user-friendly URL mapping which obscures which controller I'm using in some cases (basically gets rid of underscores, and other neat things)

Answer (score 0):

```
params[:controller]
#=> "TemplateUserController"
params[:controller][/.*[^Controller]/]
#=> "TemplateUser"

params[:controller]
#=> "UsersController"
params[:controller][/.*[^Controller]/].singularize
#=> "User"
```

And yes - in real world there are many of controllers don't refer to model

PS

Istead of `params[:controller]` you can use `Rails.controller`

Comment: Thanks, Rails.controller was exactly what I was looking for =D (I didn't even know how to get the controller name. (I'm currently working on abstracting my app as much as possible... the less code the better... just.. more comments. Which I think is ok)

Comment: Problem, I accepted too soon. I get this error: NoMethodError: undefined method `controller' for Rails:Module
Is that a rails 3 thing? I'm on 2.3.8

Comment: Ok, then use `params[:controller]` for oldest Rails

Comment: params doesn't exist in before filters =\. Didn't think that part would be relevant. butI nee dthis evaluated before my destroy method is called. so..params is a no-go

Comment: I am pretty sure that `params` is visible in before_filter

Answer (score 0):

`@Sam`'s solution of `controller_name.classify.constantize` works for all controllers, although many like me may have to lookup the doc to realize that 'controller' is not part of the name.

If your controller is to control a model though, you should consider using [inherited_resources](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources). You get many benefits, one of which is the method `resource_class`:

```
class TemplateUserController < InheritedResources::Base
  resource_class # => TemplateUser
end
```